# requestCode en un ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onactivityresult

En mi aplicación para obtener una imagen de perfil el usuario puede optar por la cámara o la galería, dejo porción del código.

```
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "");
        chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{cameraIntent});

        launcher.launch(chooser);
```

Aqui el codigo de *launcher* es decir el **ActivityResultLauncher**

```
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    // si selecciona la galeria
                    Picasso.get().load(result.getData().getData()).into(image);

                    // si selecciona la camara
                    image.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) result.getData().getExtras().get("data"));
                }
            });
```

la idea es poder filtrar qué opción pulso el usuario en el **onActivityResult** para utilizar un método u otro, antiguamente podíamos pasar un **requestCode** en **startActivityForResult** y lográbamos lo que necesito pero este método esta deprecated. Simplemente necesito saber si el usuario ha seleccionado la cámara o la galería, para más comprensión podéis utilizar el código y ver el resultado.

Comment: Cual es el problema aquì?  no se entiende mucho , te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos

Comment: *para más comprensión podéis utilizar el código y ver el resultado.* -> Tú crees que si pego eso en Android Studio va a compilar? Porque si intento ejecutar tu código voy a encontrarle muchos errores... Mayormente porque no compila! Describe correctamente el problema, que será mejor. Nadie va a tomarse las molestias de intentar comprender tu pregunta si aun por encima tenemos que montarnos un proyecto y añadir las librerías que necesite teniendo que *adivinar* qué versiones utilizas!